# how to generate menu from database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm trying to generate a nested unordered list from my SQL database. I use recursive method to nest the data. Should I put my logic in a separate htmlhelper or should I use Html.RenderAction that calls a child action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluating both options I would use `Html.RenderAction`, if you use an `htmlhelper` you must find a way to pass that menu model to all your views so the `htmlhelper` can render the html, you will need to use an `ActionFilter` and `ViewData`/`ViewBag` to pass the model.

With `Html.RenderAction` you got the benefit of having a controller to handle the job with its own model so you don't have to be dealing with complex models or `ViewData`/`ViewBag` objects and castings, you also get the benefit of caching `[OutputCache]` and control with `[ChildActionOnly]`.

Comment: So when would I use htmlhelper? Any scenario that I can think of can be done with child action methods too!

Comment: You can use htmlhelper in cases where you do not need to access the database or a separate model, logical decisions, css styling, rendering list (loops) based on the model you already have in place.